# What is the correct way to create a Javascript class?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I'm trying to figure out how to construct my Javascript classes (or singleton objects) correctly.

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.foo = 'bar';
obj.method = function() { ...}

var obj = {
    foo : 'bar',
    method : function() { ...}
}

var obj = function(){}
obj.prototype = {
    foo : 'bar',
    method: function() { ... }
}
```

I want to be able to set a couple of properties and assign the methods available.  I would also like to be able to use things like [mixins](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/) on the objects so I can extend these objects with things like [events](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/microevent.js/blob/master/microevent.js).

Comment: Rule #1: Never use `new Object()`.

Comment: @minitech, you sure? They must have made it for some reason.

Comment: @Xeoncross: Not that I'm aware of. :-)

Comment: @Xeoncross They made `new Window` too, but you can't use it ;)

Comment: @Xeoncross - They also made `new Boolean()` ;)

Comment: and new Array, and new Number, and new... Better to use the literal

Comment: Isn't it ironic that you pass a string literal to the `new String` constructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out how to construct my Javascript classes (or singleton objects) correctly.

There's a big difference between those ("classes" and singleton objects). Your first couple of examples are one-off objects (singletons). Your third (last) example creates a *constructor function* that will allow you to create multiple objects sharing the same prototype. I would recommend *augmenting* the `prototype` property on the constructor function rather than replacing it as you're doing, e.g.:

```
var Thingy = function() {   // Or use a function declaration rather than expression
    // Optional initialization code here
};
Thingy.prototype.foo = 'bar';
Thingy.prototype.method = function() {
    // Method code here
};
```

(Constructor functions, by convention, start with an upper case letter.)

Which you use (singleton or constructor function) depends on what you need.

As of ES2015 (aka "ES6"), it's simpler, although there's no new syntax for defining a non-method prototype property (your `foo`); there probably will be in ES2017 or ES2018, once [this proposal](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties) moves forward, but until then:

```
class Thingy {
    constructor() {
        // Optional initialization code here
    }
    method() {
    // Method code here
    }
}
Thingy.prototype.foo = 'bar';
```

If you need to get into inheritance hierarchies, in the old ES5 syntax there's a fair bit of plumbing involved:

```
var Base = function() {
};
Base.prototype.method = function(arg1) {
    // ...
};

var Derived = function() {
    Base.call(this);
};
Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived;
Derived.prototype.method = function(arg1) {
    // Using Base's `method`, if desired, is a bit ugly:
    Base.prototype.method.call(this, arg1);
};
```

...which is why you used to see libraries stepping in, like Prototype's `Class` stuff, or my own [Lineage](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/); those are outdated by ES2015 syntax, though, whcih makes it downright easy:

```
class Base {
    method(arg1) {
        // ...
    }
}
class Derived extends Base {
    method(arg1) {
        // Use's the superclass's `method`, if desired, is easy:
        super.method(arg1);
    }
}
```

Re the *title* of your question:

> What is the correct way to create a Javascript class?

There are several equally-correct ways to create "classes" of objects in JavaScript, because JavaScript is a very flexible language. There are standard constructor functions, "builder" functions, `Object.create` (on ES5-enabled environments) which lets you do more direct prototypical inheritance, and several others. One of the great things about JavaScript is that you get to choose your style of "class".

Answer (score 1):

you can also use something like:

```
function O(x,y) {
   this.x=x;
   this.y=y;
   this.method=function() {...}
   return this;
}

var o=new O(0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a practical solution rather than a theoretical one, you better use a framework.

- [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) has all you need, including mixins and an event system.

If you need some widgets too, consider

- [qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/)
- [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs)

Both of them provide a clean architecture and may be used without widgets, but they require a bit more learning than Backbone.

The inheritance structure that these frameworks provide feels very much like the common class-based one (think Java). That's because they create special objects internally that merely serve as `prototype`s for others, and thus take the role of classes.

For example, when you call `Ext.define('MyClass', {extend: 'ParentClass', mixins: foo, ... })`, then Ext creates a `function` "`MyClass`", and an anonymous object (`MyClass.prototype`) which holds the methods you provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting a browser or environment that supports ES5, then you can do this:

```
var Person = {
  foo: ...,
  bar: ...
};

var Mike = Object.create(Person, { baz: ... });
```