# javascript prototype propertie hookup

Tags: javascript

```
var People = function()
{
    this.FirstName = "John";
    this.LastName = "Doer";
}

var Employee = function(o)
{
    this.DateHired = "June 30";
    this.prototype = o;
}

var obj = new People();
var employee1 = new Employee(obj);
print(employee1.DateHired);
print(employee1.FirstName);
```

Output:
June 30

I expected the output should be:
June 30
Jonh

but it is not what I expected. So could someone explain me what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: how does your `print()` relate with `javacript` tag? Correct your question

Comment: It should be `console.log`, may be..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*What is the correct way to create a Javascript class?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769772/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-javascript-class)

Comment: i'm using js interactive console so print() works.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my intention was not about class. I'm trying to understand how prototype hook up works from a piece of code i read from a book:
if (typeof Object.beget !== 'function') {
     Object.beget = function (o) {
         var F = function () {};
         F.prototype = o;
         return new F();
     };
}
var another_stooge = Object.beget(stooge);
The above code work.

Comment: @hungvn: With respect, that's not the question you asked (though you may have meant to). :-) You don't use `new` with that kind of direct prototypical inheritance. (There's also no need for `beget` anymore; ES5 added `Object.create` in December 2009, which does the same thing.) Since this question is asked and answered, if you have a question about `beget`, I suggest posting a new question asking about the specific pattern you've seen.

Answer (score 13):

You've set a property called `prototype` on the *instance* created by `new Employee`, which doesn't do anything to hook up a prototype chain. The `prototype` property goes on the *function* `Employee`. That property is then used to set the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of objects created via `new Employee`.

So assuming you want `Employee` to be a subclass of `People`, you'd do it like this:

```js
// The singular is "Person", so I'll use that instead of People
var Person = function() {
  this.FirstName = "John";
  this.LastName = "Doer";
};

var Employee = function() {
  // Give `Person` a chance to do its initialization of the instance
  Person.call(this/*, possible, arguments, here*/);

  // Now carry on with the `Employee` initialization
  this.DateHired = "June 30";
};

// Make Employee a subclass of Person by
// 1. Giving `Employee.prototype` a new object whose [[Prototype]] is
//    `Person.prototype`
// 2. Ensuring that `Employee.prototype`'s `constructor` property points
//    back to Employee.
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;

// Usage
var employee1 = new Employee();
console.log(employee1.DateHired);
console.log(employee1.FirstName);
```

**However**, here at the end of 2016, we don't need to play those games anymore: We can use the `class` syntax of ES2015 (transpiling if we need to deploy the code to older browsers), which handles the plumbing for us:

```js
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.FirstName = "John";
    this.LastName = "Doer";
  }
}

class Employee extends Person {
  constructor() {
    // Give `Person` its chance to initialize the instance
    super();
    // Now carry on with the `Employee` initialization
    this.DateHired = "June 30";
  }
}

// Usage
const employee1 = new Employee();
console.log(employee1.DateHired);
console.log(employee1.FirstName);
```

Comment: Also it's possible to add 'People.apply(this, arguments);' at the start of Employee function.

Comment: @AliaksiejMaroz: Yes, but only if you need to pass along all arguments. Normally you pick and choose.

Comment: yep, you're right. My example will be good only for this special case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you. now i understood where the problem with my code is

Answer (score 0):

```
Inheritance works as below


    var People = function()
            {
                this.FirstName = "John";
                this.LastName = "Doer";
            }

            var Employee = function()
            {
                this.DateHired = "June 30";
                //this.prototype = o;
                People.call(this);
            }
            Employee.prototype=Object.create(People.prototype);
            var employee1 = new Employee();
            console.log(employee1.DateHired);
            console.log(employee1.FirstName);
```

Comment: The primary problem is that this *isn't* how inheritance works in JavaScript. There is no inheritance happening in that code. You just have a function setting properties on an object. There's also no purpose to the `obj` variable at all, you don't use the `o` argument in `Employee`, ...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Is it fine now?

Comment: It's *better* now, but still missing the `constructor` fix up, and at this point it's just duplicating my earlier answer, which isn't really useful, and it still doesn't explain anything (such as why the OP's code didn't work, and why this code does).

Answer (score -3):

When you say:

```
this.prototype = o;
```

You are essentially creating a property named "prototype" and giving it a value.
Javascript assumes that you are trying to store values in a variable named "prototype".

If you typed:

```
print(employee1.prototype.FirstName);
```

You would get

Output: John